# In Android 6, the CPU temperature showing 50-55c when I just using browser with Wifi?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I am just using UC Browser with Wifi but after some minutes the temperature reaches to 50-55c? What is the probledm?

Answer (score 1):

That's completely normal operating temperature for a CPU.  Most function perfectly fine up to at least 90° C, though on a phone will typically throttle before that to ensure that the phone as a whole does not get too hot.  Not too much more to be said without knowing how this compares to other browsers on your device (UC Browser might just be less efficient) or what you're browsing (maybe the site is poorly coded and has a lot of intensive JavaScript operations).

Comment: I would add that the temperature is so high because there is no real heat dissipation happening on a smart phone (heat pipes are in place in some phones but they just spread the heat a *little*). The chips are also incredibly tiny and the temperature readings are usually just bursts of high temps.

Comment: I don't think that temperatures get to 90°C without harm that is too high I think

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје SoCs can mostly stand that without a sweat; on-board memory, however, will take hits at temperatures upwards of 80°C-ish, with stability and data integrity gradually affected. That's quite unlikely on phones, but possible for memory-intense devices such as graphics cards (PC).